# struggling to make an xpath work

Tags: python, scrapy

I am starting at one page on a website and trying to find a link that takes me to another page to scrap.  However, for reasons that i can't work out my xpath to the link on this first page to take me to the other page is not working.  I have tried to get to the link from several directions, though none seem to work?

```
import scrapy

from urllib.parse import urljoin
from autotrader1.items import Autotrader1Item

class Autotrader1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "autotrader1"
    allowed_domains = ["autotrader.co.uk"]

    start_urls = ["https://www.autotrader.co.uk/dealers/greater-manchester/manchester/liberty-cars-10000889"]


    def parse(self,response):
        for href1 in response.xpath('//*[@class="dealer__stock-header"]/a/@href'):
           url1 = urljoin('https://autotrader.co.uk/',href1.extract())
           yield scrapy.Request(url1, callback=self.parse_dir_contents1)


    def parse_dir_contents1(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="dealerStock"]'):
            URLs = sel.xpath('.//a[@class="external title"]/@href ').extract()
            URLs = [URL.strip() for URL in URLs]
            descriptions = sel.xpath('.//a[@class="external title"]/text()').extract()
            descriptions = [description.strip() for description in descriptions]
            prices = sel.xpath('.//div/span[@class="deal-price"]/text()').extract()
            prices = [price.strip() for price in prices]
            result = zip(URLs, descriptions, prices)
            for URL, description, price in result:
                item = Autotrader1Item()
                item['URL'] = URL
                item['description'] = description
                item['price'] = price
                yield item
```

Comment: So you mean `parse_dir_contents1` is never called? or called with wrong urls?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - `parse_dir_contents1` is never called

Comment: The page is loaded with javascript that is why its not working. You need to use scrapy + splash for this

Comment: @TarunLalwani thank you for that, re-done by adding scrapy-splash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091655/scrapy-splash-not-allowing-infinite-scroll-to-complete